# Hbase tables are not getting saved. Hbase tables getting disappeared after shutdown

Tags: hadoop, hbase, apache-zookeeper

I have installed hbase standalone application and faced many troubles in running hbase shell. And then I got rid off those problems and made it run. Now It's working normally. As now I create or list or describe a table all are working fine. The table is not getting saved. When I shutdown my system the tables are getting vanished. And I have to start freshly. I'm new to hbase. I want guidance to get the rid off this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hbase tables are not getting saved.

That is because, in my case, I had not set the 'hbase.rootdir' property in hbase -> conf -> hbase-site.xml. after setting up it, I got the tables saved normally.